# ClassNotFoundException while using javaDB(apache.derby)

Tags: java, database, derby, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to run a sample project to run derby.
I run a code which found from internet. It seemed fine but print ClassNotFoundException.
Code is below;

```
package org.owls.mem.db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {

    public String framework = "embedded";
    public String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    public String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Main().go(args);
    }

    void go(String[] args)
    {
        parseArguments(args);

        System.out.println("SimpleApp starting in " + framework + " mode.");

        try
        {

            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            System.out.println("Loaded the appropriate driver.");

            Connection conn = null;
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("user", "user1");
            props.put("password", "user1");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol +
                    "derbyDB;create=true", props);

            System.out.println("Connected to and created database derbyDB");

            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            Statement s = conn.createStatement();

            s.execute("create table derbyDB(num int, addr varchar(40))");
            System.out.println("Created table derbyDB");
            s.execute("insert into derbyDB values (1956,'Webster St.')");
            System.out.println("Inserted 1956 Webster");
            s.execute("insert into derbyDB values (1910,'Union St.')");
            System.out.println("Inserted 1910 Union");
            s.execute(
                "update derbyDB set num=180, addr='Grand Ave.' where num=1956");
            System.out.println("Updated 1956 Webster to 180 Grand");

            s.execute(
                "update derbyDB set num=300, addr='Lakeshore Ave.' where num=180");
            System.out.println("Updated 180 Grand to 300 Lakeshore");

            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(
                    "SELECT num, addr FROM derbyDB ORDER BY num");

            if (!rs.next())
            {
                throw new Exception("Wrong number of rows");
            }

            if (rs.getInt(1) != 300)
            {
                throw new Exception("Wrong row returned");
            }

            if (!rs.next())
            {
                throw new Exception("Wrong number of rows");
            }

            if (rs.getInt(1) != 1910)
            {
                throw new Exception("Wrong row returned");
            }

            if (rs.next())
            {
                throw new Exception("Wrong number of rows");
            }

            System.out.println("Verified the rows");

            s.execute("drop table derbyDB");
            System.out.println("Dropped table derbyDB");

            rs.close();
            s.close();
            System.out.println("Closed result set and statement");

            conn.commit();
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Committed transaction and closed connection");

            boolean gotSQLExc = false;

            if (framework.equals("embedded"))
            {
                try
                {
                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");
                }
                catch (SQLException se)
                {
                    gotSQLExc = true;
                }

                if (!gotSQLExc)
                {
                    System.out.println("Database did not shut down normally");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Database shut down normally");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            System.out.println("exception thrown:");

            if (e instanceof SQLException)
            {
                printSQLError((SQLException) e);
            }
            else
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("SimpleApp finished");
    }

    static void printSQLError(SQLException e)
    {
        while (e != null)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e = e.getNextException();
        }
    }

    private void parseArguments(String[] args)
    {
        int length = args.length;

        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
        {
            if (args[index].equalsIgnoreCase("jccjdbcclient"))
            {
                framework = "jccjdbc";
                driver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
                protocol = "jdbc:derby:net://localhost:1527/";
            }
            if (args[index].equalsIgnoreCase("derbyclient"))
            {
                framework = "derbyclient";
                driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
                protocol = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/";
            }
        }
    }
};
```

It says EmbeddedDriver is not on classpath. What can I do?
I heard that javaDB is included in jdk(after ver.1.6, and I am using 1.7), and I already set PATH for java. Do I need extra settings to use derby?
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://db.apache.org/derby/quick_start.html#The+Basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your jar file is not present in your class path

check this link [REFERENCE](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html#derby_configure)

Comment: yep. I thought it is so natural that 'derby.jar' is included since it is basic elements of jdk. However, it needs extra setting. like your links or copy 'derby.jar' to inside of the project and add to buildpath(this is my way, but I think your suggestion is better.). Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the driver should be included after 1.6 http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/devguide/cdevdvlp40653.html.

Now Check if the path of your JAVA_HOME value is on the JDK not the JRE7.

Comment: My JAVA_HOME is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25". and as you see I am using jdk not jre. Thanks